# Margin notes in both sides using a twoside option in article

Tags: formatting, marginpar

I am trying to create two commands, each to place marginalia on the left or the right side of the page. They work in the `documentclass` `article` with the `oneside` option, but when I use `twoside`, the even pages do not show the marginal notes.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\MarginaliaL}[1]{
\reversemarginpar
\marginpar[\hfill #1]{}
}
\newcommand{\MarginaliaR}[1]{
\normalmarginpar
\marginpar[]{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\section{one}
\lipsum[1]\MarginaliaR{this world}

\section{two}
\lipsum[1]\MarginaliaL{hello!}

\section{three}
\lipsum[1]\MarginaliaL{hello again!}

\section{four}
\lipsum[1]\MarginaliaR{world}

\lipsum[3]\MarginaliaL{hello}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when you use the document class `article` with a `twoside` option, the placement of `\marginpar` flips on even pages. So the commands I wanted to create have to check for odd or even pages. That can be done with the `ifoddpage` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
% 
\newcommand{\MarginaliaL}[1]{
\checkoddpage\ifoddpage \reversemarginpar \else \normalmarginpar \fi
\marginpar[\hfill #1]{}
}

\newcommand{\MarginaliaR}[1]{
\checkoddpage\ifoddpage \normalmarginpar \else \reversemarginpar \fi
\marginpar[]{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\section{one}
\lipsum[1]\MarginaliaR{this world}

\section{two}
\lipsum[1]\MarginaliaL{hello!}

\section{three}
\lipsum[1]\MarginaliaL{hello again!}

\section{four}
\lipsum[1]\MarginaliaR{world again}

\lipsum[3]\MarginaliaL{hello world}
\end{document}
```